# какова очередность вызова слота

Tags: qt, сигналы-слоты

Допустим имеется некоторый класс:

```
class Someclass : public QObject
{
    Someclass{}
public slots:
    void send_to_socket(QTCPSocket* pSocket, QString str)
    {
        QByteArray  arrBlock;
        QDataStream out(&arrBlock, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
        out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_12);
        out << quint16(0) << str;
        out.device()->seek(0);
        out << quint16(arrBlock.size() - sizeof(quint16));
        if ( (pSocket != nullptr ) && pSocket->isValid() && pSocket->state() == (QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState ) )
            pSocket->write(arrBlock);
    }
}
```

из другого класса в том же потоке вызывается слот `Someclass::send_to_socket` два раза подряд, с разными сокетами и строкой, при этом второй подряд вызов иногда не срабатывает (на другом конце данные не принимаются), но если между ними сделать хоть какуюто задержку (достаточно просто запросить объект через каст - например так

```
wicket_reader *entry_reader = qvariant_cast<wicket_reader*>( entry_soc->property("wicket_object_pointer"));
```

и сразу все успевает отправляться.

Ранее я уже задавал вопрос по очередности вызовов слотов, мне ответили что рассматривать их как обычный поочередный вызов процедур, но что тогда происходит в данном случае? Видимо менеджер сигнал слотов пытается запускать их параллельно?

Comment: а если в connect указать `Qt::DirectConnection`, тогда какое будет поведение?

Comment: Уверен, что он второй раз не вызывается? добавь отладочную печать для проверки... Может принимающая сторона просто некорректно обрабатывает два слипшихся пакета?

Comment: Виноват, стэйт машине состояние добавил, а один переход забыл, сеть не виновата. Как удалить вопрос?